# How to focus a tab in firefox if it is already open?

Tags: javascript, firefox, tabs

I have created a desktop notification for my application. When I click the notification need to focus the tab in Firefox but it is worked in Chrome not in Firefox.

Thanks for your help.

My focused tab is inactive at the time of clicking the notification and other tab is active. At the time tab focus in Firefox is not working. If the Firefox has only one tab(my focused tab) means tab focus working. These two scenarios are working in chrome well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set focus to already opened tab in firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208115/how-to-set-focus-to-already-opened-tab-in-firefox)

Comment: @dhruv jadia, My focused tab is inactive at the time of clicking the notification and other tab is active. At the time tab focus in Firefox is not working. If the Firefox has only one tab(my focused tab) means tab focus working. These two scenarios are working in chrome well.